# How to get the value from a Form without validating the fields?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have a scala template and I've passed a form instance with a `Ticket` instance populated with my data in order to render my page `ticketForm : Form[Ticket]`. However, part of my template renders a `List<Object> items` into a `<ul>` and I don't want to pass this list as a parameter on the template as I already have it as a property on the `ticket` object itself. I was using `ticketForm.get().getItems` but it runs the validation and throws an exception.

Is there any another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `get`, just `ticketForm('myproperty')`

An example of generation radio group:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputRadioGroup.scala.html

In the case, if you want to process a list, like the `@repeat` helper

```
@helper.repeat(userForm("emails"), min = 1) { emailField =>
    @helper.inputText(emailField)
}
```

Here is the realization of the repeat helper:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/Helpers.scala#L80